# Python: which directory to work from

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, syntax-error

I'm on Windows 7 and using Python 3.6. The PATH has C:\Python36-32 and C:\Python36-32\scripts. This is my first foray into Python and I am working with a one line script which is merely:
`print("hello")`
and I'm already running into trouble.

I installed Python into C:\Python36-32. I saved hello.py to C:\Users\shea\Documents. If I open IDLE and try

```
>>> C:\Python36-32\python.exe C:\Users\shea\Documents\hello.py
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

or

```
>>> python.exe hello.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The first attempt came from a question or other reading somewhere else, I've been searching for over 2 hours for this question, that said that the complete path to the program needs to be given. Apparently, I need to add something else to another PATH to get to just using `python ...`, but I'm not worried about that at the moment. The 2nd attempt is just me trying something apparently easy out of frustration and that doesn't work either. I get the same problems with cmd. I don't know what is behind either problem. From the questions I've looked at, Python doesn't like more text after "\", but I don't know how I'd say what the name of the script is that I want to run with `python.exe`.

I think part of the problem is that the script is not in the same directory as python.exe, but I am not sure of that. Can I work with Python this way? If so, what is the right syntax to get Python to return the simple "hello" in IDLE or the cmd terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The IDLE is not the same as a terminal shell.

You can do: `File` -> `Open` and open your file then Run it from `Run` menu or by pressing `F5`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run IDLE you are running the python interpreter, not a regular shell. The python interpreter works on a specific directory, which you can check by doing:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
```

The directory it will output it's the directory the interpreter is currently in. You can change the directory the interpreter is currently in by doing:

```
>>> os.chdir(r'C:\Users')
```

In this case i changed the directory to `'C:\Users'`. You can run `os.getcwd()` again to confirm the directory changed.

Withing the interpreter, you can run scripts using the `import(<path_to_script>)` call:

```
>>> import(r'myscript.py')
```

Since i only gave the name of the file, it will search for the file on the directory the interpreter is in. Since i put the interpreter in `'C:\Users'`, it'll look for a `'C:\Users\myscript.py'` file and run the code in it. You can also pass the complete path to the `import` call, in which case it'll run the script no matter where the interpreter is currently in. The `r` before the string just tells python to take the string as it is and to not look for special characters. This is important because if you indicate your paths using `\` then python would take the next letter after every `\` as a special character, and would not read the path correctly (for instance, `\n` is a special character which indicates a new line).

If you import a script, and then do changes to it, to run it again, use the reload call:

```
>>> reload(r'myscript.py')
```

If you just want to run this on a regular terminal you just need to do:

```
python <script_file>
```

Provided the folder to the python binary is already in the environment variable PATH of Windows. In a regular shell, what you have to put on `<script_file>` follows the same rules as if it were on the python interpreter: if your command shell is already in directory of your script, then give just the name of the file, otherwise give the complete path, using `""` and `/`.

Comment: thanks for reply. This happens on my computer using IDLE shell: >>> os.chdir(r'C:\Users\shea\Documents\python') >>> os.getcwd() 'C:\\Users\\shea\\Documents\\python' >>> import(r'hello.py') SyntaxError: invalid syntax and the lead parenthesis is highlighted.